# Swift Firebase Delete Child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Need help on how to delete a specific child within a child. I am able to access the correct child through a query call, but I am not sure how to remove just that specific child because right now I am removing everything relating to that user. The picture beneath is my firebase son structure. For "posts" I want to delete "-KzV-uwXL9lbP5wbsQ7W". Maybe when I am creating the "posts" I need to add this "id" into the structure for the query call? Not sure, just thinking... thanks.

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "download_url").queryEqual(toValue: pictureImage).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                if snapshot.exists() {

                   snapshot.ref.removeValue()

                    print("snapshot exists")
                } else {
                    print("snapshot doesn't exist")
                }
            })
```

[image]

Comment: snapshot.child("KzV-uwXL9lbP5wbsQ7W") is probably the node you are trying to delete.

Comment: Well, I need something to work to where I can delete other posts as well. that will only delete that post. What if I have another post with another id? Your solution wouldn't work

Comment: I think it would be more like Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).child(postid).removeValue()

Comment: That doesn't word. I added the postID to the child and have been trying that but no luck